# Android select only one mobile number from contact list

Tags: java, android, contacts

I am developing an android app, in which I am taking contacts from contact list and showing in listview, when I display mobile number if user has two mobile number saved in a contact, then in listview his name is repeated and second mobile number is shown below his first name, so if two mobile number is saved for a particular number I need to select only first number, so what change I need to do in following code, if anybody know please help.

```
 Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();



           while (c.moveToNext())
        {
                int type = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));

                if (type == Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                {
                    Contact con = new Contact(c.getString(c
                            .getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)), c.getString(c
                            .getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER)));
                    contacts.add(con);
                }


            }
```

Comment: check `Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME` in your `contacts` list before adding.

Comment: i didnt understand.. where I need to change

Comment: before  `contacts.add(con);` check if `Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME` already added to the `contacts` list.

Comment: can u pls give that code..

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void readContacts() {
Cursor contactsCursor =getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract
                .Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
        mContactsMetaDataList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Set<String> idSet = new HashSet<>();
            if (contactsCursor.getCount() > 0) {
                while (contactsCursor.moveToNext()) {
                    String id =contactsCursor.getString(contactsCursor.getColumnIndex
                            (ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String name =contactsCursor.getString(contactsCursor.getColumnIndex
                            (ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    if(Integer.parseInt(contactsCursor.getString(contactsCursor.getColumnIndex
                            (ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                        idSet.add(name);
                        if (!idSet.contains(name)){
                            //add contact to your list here
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }finally {
            if (contactsCursor != null) {
                contactsCursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
```